# Classic Content End of Life / Retirement

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

With the January 2021 release, the ability to *edit* Classic Content will be retired along with copying and moving:

[January 2021 release - Email Studio retires the ability to edit, copy, and move classic emails and templates.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_content_and_email_creation_tools.htm&type=5)

We will still have the ability to view and send classic content.

Email Studio features not included in the retirement:

- View classic emails, templates, and content areas
- Access to Portfolio
- Sending classic email
- Landing Pages
- Email classic SOAP APIs
- Distributed Sending

**Does any one know if "viewing" also includes viewing the HTML/AMPscript code of the emails and content?** I would assume it does as Salesforce does not usually pull the rug from underneath you overnight with these sunsetting of features.

(Source: [Marketing Cloud - Classic Content Creation Retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352265&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1), [Create Classic Email End of Life](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2020_create_classic_email_end_of_life.htm&type=5))

Comment: Does anyone know if this end of life also applies to any other org types? The docs only mention it applying to Marketing Cloud?

Comment: I have confirmed with Salesforce support that only classic email templates built in Marketing Cloud Email Studio are being retired. There is no retirement announcement for the regular classic email templates yet, however it's likely we'll see this some time in the future, since they are already making first steps by retiring the Marketing Cloud ones.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @Garywoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to click the edit button you will simply not be able to save any edits. So yes you will be able to view all your code to copy it and move it to Content Builder if you desire